# Getting data from two dates in SQLite using EditText

Tags: android, string, sqlite, date, arraylist

I can't figure out how to use EditText in my Activity to search sqlite for a date range. I think I need to somehow make editText1 and 2 strings but I have no idea how to do that in my database.

In sqlite

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllsaleweekly() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
    String today = sdf.format(gc.getTime());
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM INSERTS WHERE saleDate BETWEEN '2012-Aug-16' AND '2013-Aug-21'";
```

This works perfect except I don't want those static values of 2012-Aug-16' AND '2013-Aug-21. I shows up perfectly in my arrayList by it's just static dates from sqlite.

In my Activity I have two editText...

```
EditText editText1,editText2;
edittext1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edittext2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

and I have an onClick for Button bydate

```
bydate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> saleList =  controller.getAllsaleweekly();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(whatever.this,whateverList, R.layout.whatever, new String[] {"whatever","whatever", "whatever", "whatever","whatever","whatever", "whatever"},  new int[] { R.id.whatever, R.id.whatever, R.id.whatever, R.id.whatever,R.id.whatever, R.id.v, R.id.whatever}); 
setListAdapter(adapter);




        }});
```

Comment: On button click you can get the value of Editext

      `String value1 = edittext1.getText().toString();
      String value2 = edittext2.getText().toString()` 

Then pass the values to the method

      `getAllsaleweekly(value1,value2)`

Comment: Should totally be an answer...Thanks. If i'm allowed and you post as answer I'll give you points.

Comment: i did post it as an answer and glad i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button click you can get the value of Editext

```
  String value1 = edittext1.getText().toString();
  String value2 = edittext2.getText().toString();
```

Then

```
  controller.getAllsaleweekly(value1,value2);
```

Change

```
  public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllsaleweekly(String date1,String date2)   
  {

   // use date1 and date 2 here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `onClickListener`

```
    bydate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
          String date1 = edittext1.getText().toString(); 
          String date2 = edittext2.getText().toString();
          if(date1 != null && date2 != null){ 
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> saleList =  controller.getAllsaleweekly(date1 ,date2);
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(whatever.this,whateverList, R.layout.whatever, new String[] {"whatever","whatever", "whatever", "whatever","whatever","whatever", "whatever"},  new int[] { R.id.whatever, R.id.whatever, R.id.whatever, R.id.whatever,R.id.whatever, R.id.v, R.id.whatever}); 
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

        }});
```

And

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllsaleweekly(String date1,String date2) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
    String today = sdf.format(gc.getTime());
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM INSERTS WHERE saleDate BETWEEN '" + date1 +"' AND '"+date2+"'";
```